# Unable to authenticate on Chargify REST API

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, restful-authentication, chargify

I trying to authenticate for a simple GET request on the Chargify API. I am probably missing a detail on how to pass the credential to the service.

I got the following error:

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send."
>
> "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the
>   transport stream."

The code I am using is the following:

```
const string url = "https://subdomain.chargify.com/subscriptions.json";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

string auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("apikey:x"));
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + auth;

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); //THROW ERROR

using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I am following the instructions on the Chargify API Documentation, you can consult the information here:

https://docs.chargify.com/api-authentication

https://docs.chargify.com/api-introduction

Using the chrome extension "Advanced REST Client", I do a GET request with the url above, then chrome ask for the credential in its traditional popup, I put my api key and 'x' as password, then I get an answer in json for exactly what I am expecting. So I know the api key is correct, the thing I'm missing is how to pass the information in C# through the request.

Using curl in the documentation, they give this example:

```
 curl -u api-key:x https://subdomain.chargify.com/customers.xml
```

Do you have any idea, how this -u parameter in curl should be translated in C#?

Thanks!

***EDIT***
As suggested in the comment I tried using the .NET wrapper, but I get the exact error. Here is my code sample:

```
var _apiConnection = new ChargifyConnect(url, _userName, _password);
var productList = _apiConnection.GetProductList();
```

Comment: check the following https://docs.chargify.com/api-code under [Documentation](http://chargify.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: I did, using the .NET wrapper I got the same error. I just added the code sample using this wrapper in this question.

Comment: @jmecwel see my comment about the wrapper below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the connection is just being closed with no reply, this may be related to the TLS 1.2 requirement that went into effect this week.

https://docs.chargify.com/tls-upgrade-notice

Comment: Awesome!! Indeed, adding the following just before creating my request worked: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: You can actually just set the `ProtocolType` property on `ChargifyConnect` to the same value - `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`. It does the same thing, it just calls it right before actually opening the connection, so there's no place for it to get switched back.

Comment: @djbyter thanks, good to know I can use the wrapper, it can save a lot of work!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by explicitly setting the TLS version to 1.2.  Just add this code before you make any calls to Chargify:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```